# How to import a CSS file from an external bundle resource

Tags: java, css, url, javafx, osgi

I'm trying to import an OSGi bundle resource *(a CSS file called style.css)* from another bundle called **cssBundle**:

```
public void addCSS() {
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
    Bundle[] bArray = bundle.getBundleContext().getBundles();
    Bundle cssBundle = null;
    for (Bundle b : bArray) {
        if (b.getSymbolicName().equals("cssBundle")) {
            cssBundle = b;
            break;
        }
    }
    Enumeration<URL> resources = null;
    try {
        resources = cssBundle.getResources("/resources/css/mainscreen.css");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (resources != null) {
        URL myCSSURL = resources.nextElement();
        try {
            URI uri = myCSSURL.toURI();
            File f = new File(uri);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this way, I get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

What would be the right, or better way to go about it?

```
System.out.println(myCSSURL);
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
bundle://13.1:1/resources/css/style.css
```

Is there a way I could add this onto my Scene without using URLs?

Comment: I haven't worked with OSGI, but is there a reason you wouldn't just do `scene.getStylesheets().add(uri.toString());`? (or maybe `uri.toURL().toExternalForm()`) The `stylesheets` property is a list of string representations of URLs, after all...

Comment: @James_D I'm importing the CSS resource file from a different bundle resource.

Comment: I don't really see that would matter. What do you actually get if you call `uri.toString()`? It's presumably an entry in a jar file, and the URI will indicate the jar file anyway.

Comment: @James_D `System.out.println(myCSSURL);` outputs ***bundle://13.1:1/resources/css/mainscreen.css***. Is there a way I could add this onto my Scene without using URLs?

Comment: Presumably neither of my suggestions works; if that's the case I don't have any others. Note that according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--), that string (i.e. `scene.getStylesheets().add(myCSSURL.toString())`) should be valid.

Comment: Does this question imply you have solved your previous problem? Please post a solution if so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389583/the-method-getbundleclasscapture1-of-extends-myclass-is-undefined-for-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI represeting the resource from the bundle can not be represented as a file. So the approach to create a file from the URI is not possible.

What you can do with the bundle resource is to get an InputStream for it. So you can use this to copy the stream contents to a file in the temp folder and give that file to scene.getStylesheets().add.

Another approach might be to define an Import-Package in your bundle for resources.css. This will make the file available on the classpath of your bundle. So maybe the scene.getStylesheets().add("/resources/css") will then work.

Answer (score 0):

That exception means it cannot find your file. You should investigate creating a URI to the CSS file.

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///C:/other/mydir/myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Actually, the exception really says the URI doesn't represent a file (most likely it represents an entry in a jar file).